# Python: Stop a while when a condition do if it's true?

Tags: python

I need to make an algorithm in which the person types a login and password and he has three attempts, I did a "while x <= 3" (ox has a value of 0) and then an if inside the while with the login and password condition . But how do I stop while asking for login and password 3 times even hitting the login and password on the first or second attempt?

Comment: You use: `break`

Comment: Show us your code and tell us what issue are you facing. Have you attempted to solve the problem?

Comment: use `break` to exit the while loop based on what you wanna do

Comment: I added an answer with the simplest loop so you can see how to ```break``` out. (I didn't complicate things with what happens if they fail the 3 attempts because you didn't specify it.)

Answer (score 0):

What about the `break` keyword. When you want to stop the loop just use the `break`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
attemps = 0
password = "test"

while attemps <= 0 :
    guess = input("what is your password?")
    if guess == password:
        print("You are now signed in")
        break
    else:
        attemps += 1
    if attemps >= 3:
        print("You have guessed too many times")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that hopefully helps you learn how to use `break` inside a loop:

```
correct_login = "person's name"
correct_password = "correct password"
for attempt in range(3):
    login = input('Please enter your login name: ')
    password = input('Please enter your password: ')
    if login == correct_login and password == correct_password:
        print('you have entered the correct credentials')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be something like:

```
# a dictionary of logins and passwords for example
logins = {'lothr': 'lothr2021', 'overflow_fan': 'overflower'}

def ask_to_proceed(login_dictionary):
    """
        function for asking user login and password, has tree attempts.
        :param login_dictionary: dictionary containing the registered logins and respective passwords
        """
    counter = 0  # we set the first count
    while True:
        counter += 1  # e sum up a count of attempt
        if counter == 4:
            print('Login failed')
            exit()
        print('*** Input your User and Password credentials ***')
        answer_login = input('Enter your User name: ')
        if answer_login in login_dictionary:
            answer_password = input('Enter your Password: ')
            if answer_password == login_dictionary[answer_login]:
                print(f'Wellcome {answer_login}')
                break
        if answer_login not in login_dictionary:
            print('User not in records')

ask_to_proceed(logins)
```

maybe you can fin a way to hide the inputs from screen, so it improoves.